# Group by managed metadata column

Tags: column, metadata, grouping

Is there any (non-programmatical way) to group by a managed metadata column.
My managed metadata column is in my view, but I can't select it in the 'Group-By' dropdowns, why?
I'm using a SharePoint 2013 site on sharepoint.com.

Thanks in advance,
D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grouping by a Managed Metadata Column with "Allow multiple values" set to **true** is NOT possible (it just will not work properly anyway).

If "Allow multiple values" is set to false, it works just fine. I just double-checked it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly the answer I was looking for! I must however consider the cons of having no multiple metadata now, I'll see how this works out, but thanks.