# Document Library View group by Enterprise Keywords

Tags: document-library, enterprise-keywords

I am editing a document library view. I have enabled Enterprise Keywords and added it as field in the view. Everything works fine till this.

Now I want to Group the listing by Enterprise Keywords. Unfortunately I don't see this option in the GroupBy Section the edit view screen.

Comment: Please see this post: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76771/group-by-managed-metadata-column