# How to Group By the Managed Metadata Column with Multiple values

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, grouping

I have a document library with Name Document Type and Module. Document Type and Module is managed metadata columns. Now I have group by for Document type but I can't have the same for Module column as I need to apply multiple values for this.
Can anybody please help me out this issue. I am using SharePoint 2013.

Thanks

Comment: The `Document Type` column is allowing only single value whereas `Module` allows multiple value and you have difficulty in it to use in `group by`. Correct?

Comment: Yes, I know we can't implement this directly. Is there any way to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you keen to keep values of module in a term set or are you flexible enough to shift it to a custom list and use it as a lookup column?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep values of module as a term set..

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that there is a direct way to achieve this. Read this [Group by managed metadata column on stack exchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76771/group-by-managed-metadata-column) which deny the fact that a managed meta data column with multiple values allowed can be used in grouping a list.

However if you are very keen on it, there is an article 
[Grouping by a multi-value Managed Metadata Field using XSLT and a DataFormWebPart](http://blog.claudiobrotto.com/2013/grouping-by-a-multi-value-managed-metadata-field-using-xslt-and-a-dataformwebpart/) which can throw some light on your problem. **But the performance implications are quite noticeable here because there are more operations to perform and is suitable for a list/library which is going to contain less data**

Comment: Thanks Asad, I have already checked that article..Could not understand so thought of asking here. Anyway Thanks for you for help.

Comment: What did you not understand? How can I help on that? Is it how should we use xslt?