# How to group by taxonomy fields?

Tags: document-library, content-type, list-view, managed-metadata, metadata

In a SP 2013 in-prem environment I am working in a document library. I am trying to group documents by a Taxonomy based field, but the result is totally chaotic and does not work at all. It shows all the elements in the library under each grouping.

The field I am trying to group by is not multi value, and I have inspected in the SharePoint manager also.It has the "AllowMultipleValues" set as False.

According to this blog it should work, but I have not managed to make it work:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vedap/2011/05/15/group-by-on-managed-metadata-column-taxonomy-column-and-issues/

Anybody else here that has some experience with this that the could share?

Comment: this should be straight forward with no issues. I am suspecting that it could be something related to either the view itself or the managed metadata column. I would suggest create a test list and use an add a managed metadata column (different from the one you are currently using) and see if the issue still there. I am sure you probably know how to do it, but just in case check this post on stackexchange http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76771/group-by-managed-metadata-column

Comment: You are right. My field was created as TaxnomyFieldTypeMulti

Comment: glad that helped :)